# Any haskell stack command fails on windows with this: HostCannotConnect "127.0.0.1"

Tags: windows, haskell, haskell-stack

For example:

```
> stack ghci
Writing implicit global project config file to: C:\sr\global-project\stack.yaml
Note: You can change the snapshot via the resolver field there.
HttpExceptionRequest Request {
host                 = "s3.amazonaws.com"
port                 = 443
secure               = True
requestHeaders       = [("Accept","application/json")]
path                 = "/haddock.stackage.org/snapshots.json"
queryString          = ""
method               = "GET"
proxy                = Nothing
rawBody              = False
redirectCount        = 10
responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
(InternalException (HostCannotConnect "127.0.0.1" [Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 508>: failed (Connection refused (WSAECONNREFUSED))]))
```

The curl command form the same console have no problems with resolving the url

```
> curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/haddock.stackage.org/snapshots.json


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"lts-2":"lts-2.22","lts-10":"lts-10.9","lts-9":"lts-9.21","lts-4":"lts-4.2","lts-3":"lts-3.22","lts-5":"lts-5.18","lts":"lts-11.0","lts-0":"lts-0.7","nightly":"nightly-2018-03-16","lts-1":"lts-1.15",
....
```

Tried to install the same version on the other PC - no such problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Stack issues [#3452](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3452) and [#3510](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3510) might be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting this **registry key** to **0** helped:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable
```